# What does "throttle back" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used these 2 links:

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/throttle-back?q=throttle+back+

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throttle+back

Chandler also noted that the results showed that the market may be able to **throttle back** concerns about other risks.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/23/why-the-euro-is-walking-back-its-post-french-election-spike.html

Comment: It is a **figurative/metaphorical** use of the verb, and means "to reduce" or "to ease up".  As if "worry" were the fuel driving their **concern**.  They can take their foot off the "worry pedal".  It's an awkward usage, IMO. Don't expect grace from business writers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To throttle is to squeeze someone's neck to prevent them from breathing (as a way of killing someone). Or more generally to stop the flow of gas through a pipe.

A throttle is used to control the speed of a petrol engine. Normally there is a restriction in the pipe that carries petrol (and air) to the engine. When a driver puts her foot on the pedal, this restriction is removed, more fuel gets in and the engine speeds up.

(actually, modern cars don't work like this, but that is a matter for motor vehicles stack exchange)

To "throttle back" is to lift your foot from the pedal, causing the restriction to come back, and slow the engine down.

Figuratively, to "throttle back" is to slow something down, by restricting the supply of some factor it needs. Here the result of the French Election has removed worries about the Euro. As said in a comment, it's an awkward metaphor.